# The mysterious puzzle

Tags: situation

I created this puzzle. You must think right to get the answers. This may seem very difficult. But I can assure that there is a clear logic behind this. But it takes time. Hope you like this :)

[File 1](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1u72TvdYjyvolMcfVIcwuGlLknooXeyEC/view?usp=sharing)

[File 2](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1s1XQILAXtPdLxE0LePQmNih_rts24dvP/view?usp=sharing)

The above two files are the documents describing the puzzle.

Hint 1:

> 1000 Melon and the clade of turtles (2)(2) and C Gas Rug (OR) A carp sugar age

Hint 2:

> A ninja

Hint 3:

> 1059849000

Hint 4:

> All's well that ends well

Blow my body hundred times with the shape you know and you shall see my heart. How am I feeling?